# Why would an organization use a single, *common* Active Directory account for all staff who use a multifunction photocopier?

Tags: active-directory

At a company I used to work for they had some high-end multifunction Panasonic digital photocopiers (fax/scanner/printer/photocopy etc.) used by approximately 150 staff.

For some reason, despite staff having to log on using their own AD credentials, the photocopiers were actually authenticated at some level by a single, underlying user account in Active Directory.

A failed logon by a user would register as a failed logon for the shared AD account for all the Panasonic photocopiers, rather than for the individual user's personal AD account. The limit before the shared AD account got locked out was set (at the domain level) to just five.

Predictably, multiple times per day, *someone* would type the wrong credentials (or would use their ID card with cached credentials after a password change at their PC) five times in a row, causing all users to be locked out of on all photocopiers, until the head of IT unblocked the shared account in Active Directory.

Why would a company use a shared Active Directory account to authenticate photocopiers, rather than configuring it so that failed logon attempts at the device would only lock out the *individual* user in question?

Answer (score 2):

The company I currently work for use a series of printer signons and provide them per section within the building. They do this rather than personal PINs just to avoid the headache of managing this and reducing PIN resets since a collection of people know it.

I suspect a universal single signon would be done for similar reasons, but why on earth they would stick a 5 attemps cap on it seems absurd. Especially if there are over say 30 people in the company. Might as well just write the PIN ont he photocopier.

Comment: The users don't even know the password for the common Active Directory account used to authenticate the printers - they use their own AD credentials to sign on to the printers. The printers have an address book, which updates from AD (so it knows what password each user should be using). It's weird because users are signing on to the printers with their AD credentials, then the printers use this shared, completely different AD account to authenticate with the servers. Due to this setup, users who lock everyone out never get identified, as the generic account is the one that locks everyone out.

Comment: Well that is just flat out silly. The have decided to merge two methods of working into one (user password or universal) and added an arbitrary count on password mismatch. Don't suppose there is any hint as to why it's run this way?

Comment: The lockout after 5 failed attempts isn't actually that arbitrary - it's just set in another country by a completely different part of the company where the big decisions are made (i.e. password lockout set at the domain level). I'm starting to think the IT guys in the local office just couldn't work out how to set it up properly.

Comment: Guess you have an answer as to why they're doing it then. "IT guys just couldn't work out how to set it up properly". Good a reason as any.